# white strip at top of HTML page, despite all margins, paddings, etc. set to 0

Tags: css, html

I have a white (actually, body color, ghostwhite) strip at the top of my HTML page, even though all margins, paddings, etc. etc. are set to 0.

URL: (edit: removed, because it's outdated)

I've thoroughly investigated everything I could think of, and I'm officially out of ideas what's causing this. The really strange thing is that I've copied the CSS from a test page and it works properly there, so I suspect any of boilerplate, modernizr, etc. that I use on the live page, but I've checked everything I could think of there and couldn't find a reason.

Firebug shows me that apparently the entire body is offset by exactly 2em. If I add a "top: -2em" to the  CSS, it aligns perfectly with the top of the page. But that's at best a workaround and I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks, the below answers all found the place where things went wrong. I found another solution as well: adding "float: left" to the #logo div also fixes the problem. But the overflow one seems the best solution so far.

Comment: Don't use such hacks. You need to understand CSS, not hack it.

Comment: what do you mean with hacks? what's your preferred solution?

Comment: The reason why you have a white strip on the top is because the `#logo` element and the H1 element have margins. It appears you didn't notice but I posted an answer below which details what is causing the issue and what changes need to be made to remove the issue.

Comment: I noticed. I've now made it my preferred answer.

Comment: @Tom could you please edit the question so it includes the original HTML and CSS. That makes this question more useful to future visitors

Comment: I would if I still had it around. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `#logo` DIV and the H1 element. Both have margins which (cumulatively) produce this white strip.

Remove the margin from the `#logo` element, and use padding for the H1.

---

**Update:**

Another way would be to:

- remove `margin` from #logo
- add `padding` to #logo
- set `margin:0` on H1
- remove `line-height:0.5em` from #logo

Result:

[image]

---

Btw I recommend you to include YUI CSS Reset (or some other reset sheet) to your page.

Comment: shouldn't boilerplate take care of that?

Comment: @Tom Nope. Boilerplate won't remove the margins from the H1 element. I recommend YUI CSS Reset: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Answer (score 1):

You have a top margin on the `h1` element.

```
h1 { margin: 0 0 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this to header class in `css`.

```
header {overflow: hidden;}
```